# Media Upload Directory to MMYY instead of YYYY/MM

Tags: uploads, directory

Is there a way to change the upload directory's location and format from `YYYY/MM` (`/wp-content/uploads/2013/06`) to `MMYY` (`/news/0613`)?
I've searched everywhere and could not find an answer - in fact, the latest version of WP even removed the ability to change where to even put the upload directory. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Force wp_upload_dir() to use time-based paths. */
add_filter( 'pre_option_uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', '__return_true' );

/**
 * Use the date format MMYY instead of YYYY/MM in the uploads path.
 *
 * @param  array $dir
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_104005_upload_dir( $dir ) {
    if ( preg_match( '!/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})!', $dir['subdir'] ) ) { // Check we do indeed have a date-based subdir
        $dir['subdir'] = '/' .  substr( $dir['subdir'], 6, 2 ) . substr( $dir['subdir'], 3, 2 );
        $dir['path'] = $dir['basedir'] . $dir['subdir'];
        $dir['url'] = $dir['baseurl'] . $dir['subdir'];
    }

    return $dir;
}

add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_104005_upload_dir', 100 );
```

It's a little frustrating that the filter `upload_dir` doesn't pass along the `$time` variable too, hence resorting to regex on the subdir.

**Update:** In regards to your problem, load `wp-admin/options.php` in the browser, then make sure the following values are:

```
    upload_path: news
upload_url_path: http://domain.com/news
```

If that still fails, try using the full path in `upload_path` (usually something like `/user/public_html/news`, use `phpinfo()` if not sure).

Comment: Thanks so much! When I try to upload though I get this error: "Unable to create directory news/0613. Is its parent directory writable by the server?" I've tried the whole 777 thing, changing the directory, adding a / before it, using the server path, the full path, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure that `news` exists & is 777?

Comment: Yep, it exists and it's set to 777.

Comment: what do you mean "changing the directory"?

Comment: Making a new folder, such as "news2," and making it 777.

Comment: Check out update to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing upload_path to /var/www/news and upload_url_path to http://domain.com/news fixed the issue! I didn't even know there was a options.php page.